# C# Console - Inputting and removing from an array

Tags: c#, arrays

for part of a small assignment I have, i've been asked to create an array to store names and addresses taken from input that the user gives and to be able to later delete a name and address from the array.

Any help or links to helping me understand how to achieve this would be highly appreaciated, thanks.

EDIT - The array is to be set up like an address book, and when printed to the screen it displays like so: "Bloggs, Joe"
It must be surname then forename. I know how to acquire and store the information the user will give, being their names and addresses, but I am stuck on how to add this into an array. The array doesn't have to be infinite, as I am supposed to allocate the array whatever size I wish.

At the start of the program it will be part of, the user will be given a menu, and they can choose to add a record, delete a record or print the book to the screen. So i am meant to be using methods where suitable.

Comment: Will you be doing this from a console app or a winforms app or a web (.aspx) or what? Will it need to persist after the application has exited (think save-game) or will it be sufficient to retrieve and store data during program lifetime? (If this is for a school project and it's the _end_ of the semester, persistance should be expected)

Comment: Using microsoft visual c# 2008. Yes a 'save-game' will be needed, so that when the application is opened again, the user can continue to add/delete from the array (it will be treated like an address book)

Answer (score 4):

Well, to start with, an array is the [wrong data structure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx) to use here.

Arrays are always a fixed size - whereas you want to be able to add elements and later remove them. Assuming you're using C# 2 or higher, you should probably use a `List<T>`.

Now, the next thing is to work out what `T` should be. It sounds like you want to store details of people - so you should create a `Person` class (or perhaps `Contact`) to encapsulate the name and address... that way you can have a `List<Person>`.

The next task is probably to work out how to ask the user for input and convert that input into an instance of `Person`.

Basically, break the task up into small bits - and then feel free to ask questions about any specific bits which you find hard.

Comment: I believe the person asking is a student so the only word they know is Array (and truly, what is a List<T> but an "array" of T [ok, I realize the semantic differences I mean in the more general pseudocode case])

Comment: @BenSmith ~ You should mark this answer as accepted once you understand Jon's advice (using the gray -> green check mark to the left of the answer and below the upvotes) and then ask new questions for the specific parts that are going to give you fits. We don't mind helping you walk through it, and as you can see, you had comments and answers within 5 minutes, so we're at least as fast as a TA ;) ... If you need to add more detail, edit your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember this exact same assignment from my CS classes.

The prof wanted us to use linked lists.  As John Skeet points out above, .NET has `List<T>`, which is basically a linked list (with the added feature of being able to be reference each item by index like an array)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Serializer for the saving part.

Check out the BinaryFormatter class and XmlSerializer.
XmlSerializer is preferred because the file is human-readable and efficiency is usually less important considering the type and purpose of your app.

Using XmlSerializer is as simple as:

> ```
> var filename = "c:\....\addressbook.xml";
> if (File.Exists(filename))
>    File.Delete(filename);
> using (var sw = new StreamWriter(filename))
> {
>    var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
>    xs.Serialize(sw, myAddressBook);
> }
> ```